peewe upgrade to 3.1.5.x
We are upgarding peewe to 3.15.x
when we setup peewe connection and every api request we disabled autocommit and add some manual changes in proxy intilaization.
 def begin(self):
        self.execute_sql('set autocommit=0')
        self.execute_sql('begin')

 def configure_proxy(cls, proxy):
    proxy.obj.require_commit = False
    proxy.obj.autocommit = True
    proxy.obj.commit_select = False
    proxy.obj.connect_kwargs["autocommit"] = True

 At every GET request to disable transaction we set transcation=false.

  with Using(proxy, DB_MODELS, with_transaction=False):
                //Execute

Now once we upgarde to peewe 3.15.x there is no Using function.Are we correctly disabling the transation=false in below code.
    with proxy.connection_context():
       with proxy.bind_ctx(DB_MODELS):
          models.DB_PROXY.execute_sql('set autocommit=1')
          // execute function




 

